# Convert NSData (retrieved from wcf ) to NSArray

Tags: ios, nsdata

I want to convert NSData, which I get it by accessing web service, to NSArray. How can I do it?

Here is the structure that I want to convert from NSData:

```
NSArray:
  NSDictionary1 : roomName departmentName
  NSDictionary2 : roomName departmentName
  NSDictionary3 : roomName departmentName
  NSDictionary4 : roomName departmentName
  NSDictionary5 : roomName departmentName
  ...
```

GetRoomList method of the web service returns a list. The structure of the list is above. Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><SOAP-ENV:Body><m:GetRoomList xmlns:m=\"http://http://portNumber/ilacDirektif.svc/\"><departId xsi:type=\"xsd:int\">0</departId><roomId xsi:type=\"xsd:int\">0</roomId></m:GetRoomList></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"];

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://port number/ilacDirektif.svc/"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest= [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:30];

    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/ilacDirektif.svc" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest addValue:@"port number" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLResponse* response = nil;
    NSData *data =[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: theRequest returningResponse: &response error: nil];
    NSArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:data];
    if(array){NSLog(@"%@",array); }else{ NSLog(@"Failed"); }
    if (data) {NSLog(@"%@",data);} else { NSLog(@"Failed");}
}
```

Error:

> 2013-05-31 09:59:45.208 IlacOrder[18513:11303] -[__NSCFData getFileSystemRepresentation:maxLength:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x7560860 2013-05-31 09:59:45.222 IlacOrder[18513:11303] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFData
>   getFileSystemRepresentation:maxLength:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x7560860'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x1c8e012 0x10cbe7e 0x1d194bd 0x1c7dbbc 0x1c7d94e 0xacc7b4 0xacc762 0xafac85 0xb22c7a 0x2a55 0xf4817 0xf4882
>   0xf4b2a 0x10bef5 0x10bfdb 0x10c286 0x10c381 0x10ceab 0x10d4a3 0x10d098
>   0x2460 0x10df705 0x16920 0x168b8 0xd7671 0xd7bcf 0xd6d38 0x4633f
>   0x46552 0x243aa 0x15cf8 0x1be9df9 0x1be9ad0 0x1c03bf5 0x1c03962
>   0x1c34bb6 0x1c33f44 0x1c33e1b 0x1be87e3 0x1be8668 0x1365c 0x1ded
>   0x1d15 0x1) libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

The function in .svc:

```
public List<DepartmentRoom>GetRoomList(int roomId,int departId()){
  return manager.GetRoomList(roomId,departId);
}
```

GetRoomList:

```
   public List<DepartmentRoom> GetRoomList(int departId,int roomId){
    var cmd = OracleHelper.GetOracleCommand(_conn, StoredProcedure.Procedure1);

                if (_conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    _conn.Open();

                OracleCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);

                cmd.Parameters["P_DEPARTID"].Value = departId;
                cmd.Parameters["P_ROOMID"].Value = roomId;

                OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

                object o = cmd.Parameters["P_REF"].Value;

                var roomList = new List<DepartmentRoom>();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    var departmentRoom = new DepartmentRoom
                    {
                        DepartId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["DEPARTID"]),
                        DepartmentName = dr["DEPART"].ToString(),
                        RoomId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ROOMID"]),
                        RoomName = dr["ROOM"].ToString()
                    };
                    roomList.Add(departmentRoom);
                }
                return roomList;
            }
```

Comment: What is the data sent back from the server? You can't just unarchive arbitrary data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:REQIP]];

NSData *myPostData = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"departId\":%d,\"roomId\":%d}",departId,roomId] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableData *myMutablePostData = [NSMutableData dataWithData:myPostData];

[request setPostBody:myMutablePostData];
[request setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startSynchronous];


NSMutableArray *list =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[[request responseString]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil ];

for(NSDictionary *theItem in [jsonObjects objectForKey:@"RequestMethodResult"]){
    [list addObject:[[ClassModel alloc]initWithDictionary:theItem]];
}

return list;
```

ClassModel is the structure of the Dictionary that each object item of NSMutableArray is.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it would be worth reading the documentation of the methods and classes you are trying to use. `unarchiveObjectWithFile:` takes a file path as its argument, not an `NSData`. Finding the method in the docs that takes an `NSData` as its input is left to you as an exercise.

Comment: Ok, I'll read. I used it because here they used. http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/6187-nsdatansdictionary.html

Comment: @e.ozmen Don't assume that copy-pasting works in a completely different situation. Anyways, *common sense.* Why would a method called `unarchiveObjectWithFile:` operate on anything else but a file?

Comment: I don't even see where they used it in that link...(which, by the way, is nearly as old as iOS itself).

Comment: So how can I convert NSData to NSArray?

Comment: @e.ozmen Hint: the `unarchiveObjectWithData:` method **might** work, but you should really show us the data you are receiving.

Comment: It didn't work.It gives an error. I'm searching for it." Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: incomprehensible archive (0x3c, 0x73, 0x3a, 0x45, 0x6e, 0x76, 0x65, 0x6c)'"

Comment: @e.ozmen To quote myself: "but you should really show us the data you are receiving."

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",data) gives me this.Or do you mean the data that I try to fetch from wcf?

Comment: @e.ozmen The data you are trying to unarchive.